# Error while initializing storage in contract deployment cmd using tezos-client command line interface option

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, michelson, liquidity, deploy

I am using the following command

```
originate contract new for mgr transferring qty from src running prg
```

for deploying a contract using Command Line Interface as mentioned in CLI  document. This command takes --init "data" and this can be used for initializing the storage. My contract accepts two params for initializing the storage as follow:

```
let%init storage (param1 : key_hash)(param2 : address) = (param1, param2)
```

How should I pass the parameter to initialize the storage?
I have tried multiple combinations, specifically three of them are as follow:

```
a) "(Pair : {tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg} {KT1GE2AZhazRxGsAjRVkQccHcB2pvANXQWd7})" 

b) "(Pair tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg KT1GE2AZhazRxGsAjRVkQccHcB2pvANXQWd7)"

c) "{Pair tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg KT1GE2AZhazRxGsAjRVkQccHcB2pvANXQWd7}"
```

but these combinations shows the following error:

```
a) Invalid primitive:
  1: Pair :
  2:   { tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg }
  3:   { KT1GE2AZhazRxGsAjRVkQccHcB2pvANXQWd7 }
Primitive tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg has invalid case.   

b) Invalid primitive:
  1: Pair tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg KT1GE2AZhazRxGsAjRVkQccHcB2pvANXQWd7
Primitive tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg has invalid case.

c) Invalid primitive:
  1: { Pair tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg KT1GE2AZhazRxGsAjRVkQccHcB2pvANXQWd7 }
Primitive tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg has invalid case.
```

Please explain what went wrong here?

Comment: I have same problem. I am usin folowing command: `./tezos-client originate contract ConTes for tz1address transferring 1 from tz1address running contes.fi --init 'pair (map "KT1address" 1) (map "KT1address" "2019-06-09 00:00:00")'` and get error: `Ill typed data: 1: (pair (map "KT1address" 1) 2: (map "KT1address" "2019-06-09 00:00:00"))
is not an expression of type pair (map address mutez) (map address timestamp)
From line 1 character 0 to line 2 character 71, value (pair (map "KT1address" 1) (map "KT1address" "2019-06-09 00:00:00"))
is invalid for type pair (map address mutez) (map address ti

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this supposed to be passed like this:

```
'(Pair "tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg" "KT1GE2AZhazRxGsAjRVkQccHcB2pvANXQWd7")'
```

Comment: Not sure whether I should remove this question or not as this is a trivial issue.